# Visual Studio Code seems to be configured badly. Emmet (tab+enter) problem, now my Life-Server (fresh install) will not work properly.. what?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, fedora, npm-live-server

I did a fresh install of Visual Studio Code on my Fedora-Linux workstation a few weeks ago and started using it since yesterday.

I started working on my Course JavaScript this morning, all motivated, and when I tried to make a default index.html file by using the default keys--> [!] <kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, I didn't get the normal result which is, a complete html skeleton (!DOCTYPE).

Fixed that within 15 minutes.

Next:

I need to install a Extension called Live-Server, so I did.
Now the assignment says--> open "index.html" file with right-click and look for "open file in server" and execute.

Again. No response! Not even a option found that's called "open in live-server"!

This is bloody time consuming/annoying.

Did I forget to do/config something after installation, or is it just VS-code being a pain?

Answer (score 0):

By default the `emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab` feature will be disabled.
You need to enable it, inorder to get those recommandations and boiler codes

To Enable `emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab` 
Go To `File` >  `Preference` > `settings`
Search for `emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab` and then enable that

Now check in the edior, it will work